# Oracle: detect exception in type construtor during bulk collect

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk

Environment: Oracle 11g
I have a type ty1 with some arguments like s1, s2.

If I use it like this:

```
SELECT ty1(s1,s2) BULK COLLECT INTO l_collection_of_ty1 FROM ...
```

I get a collection of ty1.

Now if there is an exception raised inside one of the constructor calls of ty1 the corresponding element of my collection is set to NULL, but the overall SELECT works (no exception, collection returned).

My question, can I detect this right after the SELECT without having to loop over the collection? Is there maybe even a way to access the original error message in a similar way as `SQL%BULK_EXCEPTION` does for DML?

One workaround I thought of is to not use the constructor during BULK COLLECT, but read collections of s1 and s2, then construct the TYPE in my own loop where I can handle the exception, but that is much more code and I would prefer it if Oracle has some build in way.

Comment: Just to clarify, is that element of the collection null, or is it a `ty1` object with null attributes? Is your constructor function catching the exception that is being raised? How do you know there is an exception at all? [An MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be useful here.

Comment: and the details:
the element is NULL, not ty1. It cannot be ty1, because the constructor did not finish and was left via exception. I know that, because a "when others" handler logged and reraised it.

Comment: I did not include the key detail in my question: the exception that is thrown is NO_DATA_FOUND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small test case for you and the exception has to be swallowed inside ty1 and not raised, because otherwise the select would not finish successfully:

```
create or replace function p1 (v1 number) return number
as
begin
if v1 = 1 then
return 1;
elsif v1 = 2 then
raise_application_error(-20010,'err 2');
else
raise_application_error(-20010,'err 3');
end if;
end;
/

declare
type type1 is table of number;
col1 type1;
begin
select p1(level) bulk collect into col1 from dual connect by level <=3;
end;
/
```

Result:

```
Error report -
ORA-20010: err 2
```

So my suggestion to you is - if you want to stay close to your solution - that at the place where you handle the exception in ty1, you write the exceptions to a table. You can then access this table to find the exceptions and don't need to loop through the whole collection. But honestly, what's wrong with looping in PL/SQL over a collection, it's all in memory? HTH

Comment: Thanks for you test, it opened my eyes that I left out the key detail, because I did not noticed its importance: The exception that is thrown in my type constructor is NO_DATA_FOUND. It turns out that ONLY this exception is dropped by the bulk collect, all others get though.

Comment: I accept your answer because it was closest to what I did: I just had to catch NO_DATA_FOUND and wrap it as a user-definded exception similar to your example.

Answer (score 1):

here is a testcase that demonstrates that all exceptions are thrown through a bulk-select, but NO_DATA_FOUND is dropped.

```
-- remember to retreive dbms_output
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p1 (v1 PLS_INTEGER)
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
   CASE v1
      WHEN 1
      THEN
         RAISE ACCESS_INTO_NULL;
      WHEN 2
      THEN
         RAISE CASE_NOT_FOUND;
      WHEN 3
      THEN
         RAISE COLLECTION_IS_NULL;
      WHEN 4
      THEN
         RAISE CURSOR_ALREADY_OPEN;
      WHEN 5
      THEN
         RAISE DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX;
      WHEN 6
      THEN
         RAISE INVALID_CURSOR;
      WHEN 7
      THEN
         RAISE INVALID_NUMBER;
      WHEN 8
      THEN
         RAISE LOGIN_DENIED;
      WHEN 9
      THEN
         RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
      WHEN 10
      THEN
         RAISE NOT_LOGGED_ON;
      WHEN 11
      THEN
         RAISE PROGRAM_ERROR;
      WHEN 12
      THEN
         RAISE ROWTYPE_MISMATCH;
      WHEN 13
      THEN
         RAISE SELF_IS_NULL;
      WHEN 14
      THEN
         RAISE STORAGE_ERROR;
      WHEN 15
      THEN
         RAISE SUBSCRIPT_BEYOND_COUNT;
      WHEN 16
      THEN
         RAISE SUBSCRIPT_OUTSIDE_LIMIT;
      WHEN 17
      THEN
         RAISE SYS_INVALID_ROWID;
      WHEN 18
      THEN
         RAISE TIMEOUT_ON_RESOURCE;
      WHEN 19
      THEN
         RAISE TOO_MANY_ROWS;
      WHEN 20
      THEN
         RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
      WHEN 21
      THEN
         RAISE ZERO_DIVIDE;
      ELSE
         RETURN v1;
   END CASE;
END;
/

DECLARE
   TYPE type1 IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

   col1   type1;
BEGIN
   FOR ii IN 1 .. 22
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         SELECT p1 (ii)
           BULK COLLECT INTO col1
           FROM DUAL;

         IF col1 (1) IS NULL
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (TO_CHAR (ii, '00') || ': NULL');
         ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (TO_CHAR (ii, '00') || ': ' || col1 (1));
         END IF;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                  TO_CHAR (ii, '00')
               || ': exception '
               || SQLCODE);
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: interesting. thanks for the demonstration. now, that we know it, googling for it even reveals this is documented behaviour: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#sthref2219

`Because the processing of the BULK COLLECT INTO clause is similar to a FETCH loop, it does not raise a NO_DATA_FOUND exception if no rows match the query. You must check whether the resulting nested table or varray is null, or if the resulting associative array has no elements [...]`

Comment: good link to the oracle docs. Though the documentation does not mention the case that multiple rows are returned, of which some are NULL, for example because a type constructor was exited by NO_DATA_FOUND exception.

Answer (score 0):

I see only two options.

1. An exception is consumed inside constructor.
2. The another constructor is in use.

Example:

```
create or replace type ty1 as object (p1 number
, constructor function  ty1 (p1 varchar2) 
    return self as result);

create or replace type body ty1 
is 
  constructor function ty1 (p1 varchar2) 
    return self as result is
    x number;
  begin
   raise_application_error(-20000,'Always Exception');
   return;
  end;
end;
```

Test 1 no exception:

```
declare
 type l_collection_of_ty1 is table of ty1;
 a varchar2(4000);
 x   l_collection_of_ty1;
begin 

--test1   select ty1(level) bulk collect into x from dual connect by level < 10;
     -- no exceptions 
 --test2  select ty1(level||1) bulk collect into x from dual connect by level < 10; 
       -- exceptions

  --test3 select ty1(null) bulk collect into x from dual connect by level < 10; 
       -- exceptions
end;
```

In Test1 db is using Attribute-Value Constructor. It is generate by default.
In Test2 db is using user defined constructor.
In Test3 db is not able to find out which constructor should be used.()

Comment: no, actually the NO_DATA_FOUND exception is special in that case. It can leave the type constructor as thrown exception but is not propagated by the bulk select. Please see my demonstration script below.

Comment: I accept your answer because it was closest to what I did: I just had to catch NO_DATA_FOUND and wrap it as a user-definded exception similar to your example.